# I am trying to make a table of all the possible connections in separate graphs

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to make separate graphs of all the possible connections between 2 and 12 nodes in which every node is connected. I can achieve the highest node connections possible, but do not understand how to separate the connections into graphs.

Here is the code I started with Table[UndirectedGraph[Flatten[Table[i -> j, {i, 12}, {j, 12}]]], 13]. I am only getting one example, but multiple copies of it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Table[UndirectedGraph[Flatten[Table[i->j, {i,k}, {j,k}]]], {k,2,12}]
```